# Trying JSON_ARRAYARG in active record query to group by daytime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have designed

```
query = "SELECT date_format(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p'), JSON_ARRAYARG(contact_id) FROM #{table_name } where id = 123 GROUP BY date_format(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p')"
```

The above query provides me the array of contact_ids with date as a key.
Now I need to convert this query into the active record but aggregators are not working.

```
CampaignOpen.where('campaign_id = ? ', 9891).select("DATE_FORMAT(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p')","JSON_ARRAYAGG(contact_id)" ).group("date_format(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p')").as_json
```

Now, the date_format and JSON_ARRAYARG not being executed and giving the results like that

```
[{"id"=>nil, "date_format(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p')"=>"30/05/2016 01:05 PM", "JSON_ARRAYAGG(contact_id)"=>"[24, 1, 1, 1]"}, {"id"=>nil, "date_format(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p')"=>"31/05/2016 08:05 PM", "JSON_ARRAYAGG(contact_id)"=>"[1]"}]
```

what I am expecting is

```
{"30/05/2016 01:05 PM"=>"[24,5,6,7]", "31/05/2016 08:05 PM"=>"[1,3,4,5]"}
```

Anyone is having a suggestion about how we can use these two aggregate functions here. Or any clean approach of doing this?

Comment: You don't need to separate the arguments of `select` by comma, remove it and try again (`select("DATE_FORMAT(recorded_at,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %p'), JSON_ARRAYAGG(contact_id)")`).

Comment: no luck! getting the syntax error instead

Comment: What's `for ` and what does `CampaignOpen.for(1)` return?

Comment: two suggestions: 1. append your query with `to_sql` to see how `ActiveRecord` is interpreting it, and 2. take your working query (`query`) and wrap it in ActiveRecord with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)`

Comment: I note that your working query uses `JSON_ARRAY` and your failing query uses `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, is that intentional?

Comment: @LesNightingill, it does not work either way. Not intentional.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, its basically for shards switching mechanism. It works in the same way.

Comment: it would help us to help you if you formatted your one-line code samples for better readability. I tried to edit, but apparently you rejected the edit.